# Octave UART Transmission Speed

Tags: octave, uart, stm32f4

I'm currently using an STM32F4 nucleo board, I programmed it and everything works well.

I wanted to receive the UART data directly via octave, so I installed the instrument-control package and so far everything is working, I am indeed getting my uart data.

The problem is that it is really slow, I'm like getting 1 second worth of data in 2 or 3 seconds and sometimes it takes even 10 seconds.

here is my octave script :

```
pkg load instrument-control
clear all;
close all;
clc;

mySerial = serial("COM9", 115200)
srl_flush(mySerial)
i = 1;

while(1)
[data, count] = srl_read(mySerial, 1);
dataChar(i) = char(data)

if(kbhit(1) == 'k')
break
endif

i = i + 1;
endwhile

fclose(mySerial)
```

I am a beginner when it comes to the instrument-control package!

Comment: I don't know much about the instrument-control package, but the `datachar(i) = char(data)` approach is inefficient, since you are "expanding" the array each time you assign to it, which causes it to be relocated from memory each time. It would be best if you preallocate an array instead. Also, is there a reason why you read 1 byte at a time instead of several? Loops in octave can be slow, because they need to interpret all the instructions in turn. If you can read more bytes in that single step, it may speed things up a bit. (see https://docs.octave.org/latest/Miscellaneous-Techniques.html)